# Filter within groups based on another table in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables with the following schemas:

*table_1*

```json
{
    "userId": STRING,
    "timestamp": STRING
}
```

*table_2*

```json
{
    "userId": STRING,
    "lastTimestamp": STRING
}
```

For each `userId` in *table_1* I want to keep only the `timestamp`s where `timestamp < lastTimestamp`. I have tried several attempts, the last one being:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `table_1`
GROUP BY userId
HAVING timestamp < (SELECT lastTimestamp FROM `table_2` GROUP BY userId)
```

This obviously does not work as I do not have any aggregations in the query. I would appreciate any pointers.

Sample *table_1*

| userId | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| John | 2021-08-14 |
| John | 2021-08-19 |
| John | 2021-08-20 |
| Jane | 2021-08-01 |
| Jane | 2021-08-02 |
| Jane | 2021-08-10 |

Sample *table_2*

| userId | lastTimestamp |
| --- | --- |
| John | 2021-08-16 |
| Jane | 2021-08-08 |

Expected results

| userId | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| John | 2021-08-14 |
| Jane | 2021-08-01 |
| Jane | 2021-08-02 |

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I updated the original question to include sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 

t1.*,
t2.lastTimestamp
from t1
inner join t2
on t1.userId = t2.userId
and t2.lastTimestamp > t1.timestamp

or 

select 

t1.*,
t2.lastTimestamp
from t1
inner join t2
on t1.userId = t2.userId
where t2.lastTimestamp > t1.timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with an inner join as @trillion suggests.  What you appear to be trying, though, is to use a correlated subquery, which is also a reasonable approach:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM `table_1` t1
WHERE t1.timestamp < (SELECT t2.lastTimestamp
                      FROM `table_2` t2
                      WHERE t2.userId = t1.userId
                     );
```

Note that this will return an error if `table_2` has duplicate `userId`s.